# Max number of configurations of a Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines, time-complexity, space-complexity

I was wondering about a result in the Sipser book which states that any $f(n)$ space bounded Turing machine also runs in time $2^{O(f(n))}$.

Is this because a configuration consists of a state, a position of the head and the contents of the work tape, which is $\vert Q \vert \cdot f(n) \cdot \vert \Gamma \vert ^{f(n)}$. To be honest I'm not quite sure why this is equal to $2^{O(f(n))}$. Wouldn't this only be the case when your work tape alphabet consists of 2 symbols?

Probably a silly question, but thanks anyway.

Also, I did not quite understand if this result changes when we consider logspace bound Turing machines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's right.  If there are $k$ possible configurations, then any such Turing machine either runs in time at most $k$, or it loops forever.  That's because if it runs for at least $k+1$ time steps, some configuration must be repeated; and if a configuration is repeated, it will continue repeating forever.

Let $|\Gamma|=2^c$, i.e., $c = \lg |\Gamma|$.  Then $|\Gamma|^{f(n)} = (2^c)^{f(n)} = 2^{c f(n)} = 2^{O(f(n)}$.  For similar reasons, $\vert Q \vert \cdot f(n) \cdot \vert \Gamma \vert ^{f(n)} = 2^{O(f(n)}$.  So, the number of possible configurations of a $f(n)$-space-bounded Turing machine is $2^{O(f(n)}$, and thus any such machine must either halt in time at most $2^{O(f(n)}$ or loop forever.

Comment: Oh ok, this makes sense. So we can essentially represent an arbitrary tape alphabet size, $\vert \Gamma \vert$ with some constant so that  $2^c = \vert \Gamma \vert$.  thank you!

Comment: @JohnnyPandeleo, yup!  You got it.  The tape alphabet is fixed and doesn't vary depending on the length of the input, which is why $|\Gamma|$ is a constant.